# MongoDB Like Query (starting letter or word find query)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a **MongoDB** query as mentioned below:

```
Mailbox.find({ subject: new RegExp(query , 'i') });
```

This query gives me all the results which contains the query.For example my query is test then the output displays all the results which contains 'test'.

If i want results which have only starting letter 't' or word 'test' , how can it be done ?

Comment: something like `/^test.*/`

Comment: Do you mean you want results that begin with "t", or word "test" at any where, or you want both "t" and "test" only at the beginning?

Comment: but the word "test" is subset of words starting with "t". if you want to get all the the words starting with "t", you will get "test" word automatically

Comment: if i type 'test' to search then it displays all the results that contains 'test' even it is present in the middle of a sentence.I need results where the 'test' is present only in the starting of the sentence.

Comment: That's what @Sammaye said, the symbol "^" means starts with. find PCRE regular expression documents here: http://www.pcre.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a general regex question and should be searchable

```
/^test/
```

The ^ caret signifies the start of the line.

Searching from the *start* is also advised in mongo for efficiency, meaning avoiding collection scans. More information on the forms of this, look at [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) in the documentation.

Keep this as a bookmark, and a reference for any other alterations you may need.

http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/